# Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a for-loop base on my array

`var lists = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ];`

---

## JS

```
for ( i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {

    // console.log(lists[i]);

    $(".sa-report-btn-"+lists[i] ).click(function () {
        $(".sa-hide-"+lists[i]).removeClass("hidden");
        $(".sa-report-"+lists[i]).addClass("hidden");
    });

    $(".sa-hide-btn-"+lists[i]).click(function () {
        $(".sa-hide-"+lists[i]).addClass("hidden");
        $(".sa-report-"+lists[i]).removeClass("hidden");
    });
}
```

Am I doing it correctly ? I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined`
Can I concat each loop with my jQuery selector like this --> `$(".sa-hide-"+lists[i])` ? just curious ...

Comment: You need a `var` declaration for `i`.

Comment: You should declare you `i` : `for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {`

Comment: When the event is triggerred, the variable i is not available. declare var i before the loop.

Comment: @Pointy - a `var` declaration won't create closures for the value of the `i`, isn't this a duplicate, at least I thought so, adding an IIFE would solve the issue ?

Comment: @adeneo oh well that's certainly true. (It's separate from the declaration issue but it's the next thing the OP will run into.)

Comment: @man_luck: Yes it is. This is JavaScript. Functions are closures.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First off, it sounds like you're using strict mode — **good**! It's saved you from falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

There are two issues with the code.

The first one is that you're missing the declaration for `i`. You need to add `var i;` above the loop, e.g:

```
var i;
for ( i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
// ...
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
```

Note, though, that even in that latter example, the `i` variable is function-wide, not limited to the `for` loop.

The second one is more subtle, and is outlined [in this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?lq=1): Your `click` handlers will have an *enduring reference* to the `i` variable, not a copy of it as of where they were created. So when they run in response to a click, they'll see `i` as the value `lists.length` (the value it has when the loop has finished).

In your case, it's really easy to fix (and you don't have to declare `i` anymore): Remove the loop entirely, and replace it with `Array#forEach` or `jQuery.each`:

```
lists.forEach(function(list) {

    $(".sa-report-btn-" + list).click(function () {
        $(".sa-hide-" + list).removeClass("hidden");
        $(".sa-report-" + list).addClass("hidden");
    });

    $(".sa-hide-btn-" + list).click(function () {
        $(".sa-hide-" + list).addClass("hidden");
        $(".sa-report-" + list).removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

If you need to support really old browsers, you can either shim `Array#forEach` (which was added in 2009, as part of ECMAScript5), or you can use `$.each` (`jQuery.each`) instead:

```
$.each(lists, function(index, list) {
// Note addition ------^
    $(".sa-report-btn-" + list).click(function () {
        $(".sa-hide-" + list).removeClass("hidden");
        $(".sa-report-" + list).addClass("hidden");
    });

    $(".sa-hide-btn-" + list).click(function () {
        $(".sa-hide-" + list).addClass("hidden");
        $(".sa-report-" + list).removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

Note that we don't actually use `index` anywhere in our callback, but we have to specify it because `$.each` calls our callback with the index as the first argument, and the value as the second. (Which is why I prefer `Array#forEach`.) So we have to accept two arguments, with the one we want being the second one.