# Reference Error on line 7: i is not defined JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a for loop to iterate through an array called "synonyms"; then I want to  push a greeting string with the format "Have a [synonym] day!" into a new "greetings" array.

I encounter the following error when executing my code:
Reference Error on line 7: i is not defined

```
const synonyms = ['fantastic', 'wonderful', 'great'];
const greetings = [];

// 1.
// Loop through the synonyms array. Each time, push a string into the greetings array. 
// The string should have the format 'Have a [synonym] day!'
for (i = 0; i < synonyms.length; i++) {
  let newString = "Have a "+ synonyms[i] + " day!";
  greetings.push(newString);
}
```

I think the for loop is set up correctly. What's causing my error and any other suggestions to refactor would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120478/uncaught-referenceerror-i-is-not-defined)

Comment: This logic works without an error.  What's the issue?  Or is this a tslint/use strict "error"?

Comment: @Taplar Are you implying that they shouldn't use strict mode?

Comment: No.  I'm pointing out that the logic outside of that, does not have an error. @JohnMontgomery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initialization step in the for loop is missing the let keyword when declaring the variable

```
const synonyms = ['fantastic', 'wonderful', 'great'];
const greetings = [];

// 1.
// Loop through the synonyms array. Each time, push a string into the greetings array. 
// The string should have the format 'Have a [synonym] day!'
for (let i = 0; i < synonyms.length; i++) {
  let newString = "Have a "+ synonyms[i] + " day!";
  greetings.push(newString);
}
```